# More efficient split-with in clojure

Tags: clojure, linked-list

Clojure's `split-with` function is quite handy, but has to traverse the leading part of the seq twice, as it is literally implemented as `[(take-while pred coll) (drop-while pred coll)]`.  Still, it is fairly easy to write a (tail-recursive) version that traverses the leading part only once (put the leading part in an accumulating vector, etc.).

However, I would like to extract the first element of a *list* that satisfies a predicate and return the both the element, and the remaining list (i.e. `(concat (take-while pred coll) (next (drop-while pred coll)))`) -- hopefully in a single pass.  If I were using some imperative language, I would just traverse the list, holding onto the last cell, and, once I get the element to pop out, fiddle with the "next pointer" of the previous cell to reconstruct the modified list, but this seems out of question in a functional language.

So is there a way to do that efficiently in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `split-with` (and similar tasks where you want to produce two outputs from one input), you can have any two of

- Laziness
- Immutability
- Perfect efficiency.

For example, if you don't want laziness (of the first "dropped" portion), you can get the other two by implementing a tail-recursive version as you suggest.

All this is not really applicable to your current question, since you only want one output sequence, and I recommend kotarak's solution (or something else like it). However, I thought you might like an explanation for why Clojure's built-in `split-with` traverses the input sequence twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can always drop down to `lazy-seq` for special requirements.

```
(defn splice-tail
  ([pred coll] (splice-tail pred 1 coll))
  ([pred n coll]
   (lazy-seq
     (when-let [s (seq coll)]
       (let [fst (first s)]
         (if (pred fst)
           (cons fst (splice-tail pred n (rest s)))
           (nthnext s n)))))))
```